# How to use CONVERT function in Athena. Error: Column 'bigint' cannot be resolved

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

In AWS athena when I use the convert function I keep getting the following error

```
select convert(bigint,(split_part(address,'.',1))) 
     + convert(bigint,(split_part(address,'.',2))) as sum 
from table
```

> Error code: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 2:9: Column 'bigint' cannot be resolved

for example value of address is 11.22 and so I would like to return 11 and 22 as bigint and 33 as sum. Does anyone have a fix for this? I am stuck

Answer (score 0):

Use *CAST*

```
SELECT 
      CAST(split_part('11.22','.',1) AS INTEGER) 
    + CAST(split_part('11.22','.',2) AS INTEGER) AS sum
```

A cleaner and scalable solution can use *regexp_extract_all* and *reduce*

```
SELECT reduce(regexp_extract_all('11.22', '\d+'), 
              0, 
              (s, x) -> CAST(s AS INTEGER) + CAST(x AS INTEGER), 
              s -> s)
```